# How To with Partial Function Application in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

I am trying to use partial application to shorten the following valid function definition:

```
ltest50 n = take 50 (iterate ltestonce n)
```

I thought something like:

```
ltest50 = take 50 (iterate ltestonce)
```

or

```
ltest50 = take 50 (iterate ltestonce$)
```

would do the trick, but no joy. What is the best way to do this in Haskell?

Comment: You might want to know there is a haskell wiki [page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) on this.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has the "*dot operator*" or "*function composition*" [`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-46-) for this:

```
ltest50 n = take 50 (iterate ltestonce n)
```

is equivalent to:

```
ltest50 = take 50 . iterate ltestonce
```

`(.)` is defined as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

or a bit shorter:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f $ g x
```

Since it is a symbol placed between brackets, that means it can be used as `.` as an infix operator, so:

```
ltest50 = take 50 . iterate ltestonce
```

is "*syntactical sugar*" for:

```
ltest50 = (.) (take 50) (iterate ltestonce)
```

At least in Flanders (the Dutch part of Belgium) the operator is sometimes informally called "after" because you apply `f` after you have applied `g` on a variable.